# How to correctly change image size if I want to have 50x50?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, sample-size

I have two sets of images persons (3x48x128) and backgrounds (3x50x50). So I want to train a neural network classifier with input (3x50x50). So how to correctly update images from the first set? Do I need to expand images and then scale them or I need only to scale them?